# How to print out the result of a SWI-Prolog query from C# using Swi-cs-pl library

Tags: c#, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to understand how the Swi-cs-pl library works by doing my own little program, but I cannot printout any result from a query [based on the example from SWI-Prolog web.](http://www.lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/Generated/Index.aspx)

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SbsSW.SwiPlCs;

namespace HolaMundo
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            if (!PlEngine.IsInitialized)
            {
                String[] param = { "-q" };  // suppressing informational and banner messages
                PlEngine.Initialize(param);
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(hader, nevar))");
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(father(hader, sergio))");
                PlQuery.PlCall("assert(brother(nevar, sergio):- father(hader, nevar), father(hader, sergio))");



                //How do I write out in a Console the answer for a query like:
                // brother(nevar, sergio)


                PlEngine.PlCleanup();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

As I said on my code, I just want to query something basic like: `brother(nevar, sergio).` and get any answer from Console like `true` or whatever.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does `PlQuery.PlCall("father(hader, sergio)");` work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. C# says:
Unhandled Exception: SbsSW.SwiPlCs.Exceptions.PlException: call/1: Undefined procedure: father/2

Comment: Maybe you can try something like `var q = new PlQuery("father(hader, sergio)");` and then `Console.WriteLine(q.ToString());`

Comment: Or just `PlQuery q = new PlQuery("father(hader, sergio)");`

Comment: It works, but only prints: SbsSW.SwiPlCs.PlQuery

Comment: Which one did you try?

Comment: Both of them, and they just print SbsSW.SwiPlCs.PlQuery on Console.

Comment: How about var q = new PlQuery("father(hader, sergio)"); and then Console.WriteLine(q);

Comment: Same result. I think something is missing in the q properties. The library shows q.Solution or q.SolutionVariables with a foreach but no idea what to do.